# change firefox policy DisableAppUpdate to false

Tags: permissions, firefox

I'm trying to change firefox policy DisableAppUpdate to false, policies.json is read only even though I'm logged in as root (file owner).
Spent hours searching for answers, & nothing works.
I feel like I'm banging my head against the wall, hours & hours researching trying diff methods, no luck.

below is the (failing) methods recommended by multiple sources using terminal:

```
root@sikkitty:/snap/firefox/280/distribution# ls -l policies.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 53 Oct 30 15:15 policies.json
root@sikkitty:/snap/firefox/280/distribution# gedit policies.json
root@sikkitty:/snap/firefox/280/distribution# sudo gedit policies.json
```

even though I'm logged in terminal as root, the file remains read-only.

also tried to change ownership:

```
root@sikkitty:/snap/firefox/280/distribution# chown suvana policies.json
chown: changing ownership of 'policies.json': Read-only file system
root@sikkitty:/snap/firefox/280/distribution#
```

---

The reason I wasted 2 days trying to get around this ridiculous problem is the option to ask if i wanted to save passwords in FF privacy settings was greyed out. 
"Your browser is being managed by your organization" wtf...

Kept trying different random things out of frustration and found a workaround.

Setting it to never remember history locks out that option - instead set it to custom settings & clear history when FF is closes enables the checkbox that sets FF to ask if you want to save your password.

I hope this will help someone down the road.

Comment: You might want to see:  https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/firefox-auto-update-prompt/10731  Snap apps are read only, and one person looks like they kind of got it by repacking the snap.

Comment: I found a workaround, added it to my original post. Thank you Terrance for taking the time to respond. =)